# How to step-select vertices to side?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I'm trying to unwrap a complex model with a lot of vertices, for that I need to mark some seams and later manually adjust the unwrapping UVs.

I'm looking for a tool or a short-cut that would let me step-select to side. For example there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to increase/decrease selection, but what I'm looking for is to simply step to side. Like this example:

[image]

Comment: You could try to hold `Ctrl` while clicking edges / vertices needed, see [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36047/is-there-a-way-to-choose-a-beginning-and-ending-edge-and-auto-select-all-the-edg). Note that it tries to find the shortest path, but there may be many paths, so parts of paths could be selected randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a simple way exists *yet*.

A workaround could be to use vertex groups. By selecting a centre vertex and then selecting side of active to select all the vertices on the side you don't want, you can then create a vertex group and assign these vertices to the group.

With the vertex group setup you can select the centre vertices and expand your selection, then deselect the vertices in the group, which will leave you with only vertices on one side of your mesh selected.

[image]

I think you may even want to select only one new edge loop each time, in that case, after deselecting the vertices to one side you can assign the newly selected vertices to the group, then the next time you expand the selection and deselect you will also deselect the previous loop and all the previously selected vertices.

[image]

As you are saving your progress each time you can perform any steps you want between each step, you can always select the group vertices and expand then deselect to get the next loop.

Comment: I think I can actually make a macro and bind it to a short-cut! Thank you for your answer, it's really amazing how knowledgeable the blender community is!

Comment: @CreativeMagic can u tell me how to make a new macro save. I have video on youtube but its half not shown how to make new macro save and use it. Is there any link or video from how to make macro use save etc