# How to increase the selection

Tags: edges

I have a cube and sub divided 25 and i have selected the center of the edge and i want to grow the selection on the top part only when i press ctrl+ it grow from center and spread top and bottom part i just want it grow on the top part.[image] Is there any way to grow selection to top only

Comment: ctrl+up arrow disappear the modifier and outliner and no selection grows

Comment: i think u did not get my question what i mean i want to grow the selection in top or bottom direction not in both the direction same time i do not want to create any loop cut

Comment: Does [this help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41662/935)?

Answer (score 2):

You can select all the bottom vertices and <kbd>H</kbd> hide them, then select your starting point and expand the selection as desired. When the selection is maden you should save it to a vertex group because when you unhide (<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>) the rest of the mesh, the previousely hidden vertices will be added to the current selection.