# Is there a way to select the lines between two verts?

Tags: uv

So I have recently been working with objects made with photogrammetry that I need to UV Unwrap. For that, I want to mark the seams of course but I find it very hard to select the lines I want to mark as seams because the mesh is triangulated. If I could just select two vertices and then the shotest way between those points that would be super useful. If not then what other methods would you suggest to UV unwrapping such a mesh?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36047/is-there-a-way-to-choose-a-beginning-and-ending-edge-and-auto-select-all-the-edg

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode:

1. Select first vertex.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and select last vertex.

Comment: Ctrl+select is enough. Ctrl+Shift+Select does something different

Comment: Ctrl-Shift [fills the region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#shortest-path) between the vertices. Ctrl selects the shortest path, with various options.